# HighFaces support for latest Highcharts version

Tags: jsf, highcharts

HighFaces 1.3 jar is working great.

Is there way to download code. Does HighFaces work if we embed latest Highcharts version

I am not able to pull code from HighFaces sourceforge website to see if embedding latest version of Highcharts works.
svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/highfaces/code/trunk highfaces-code

Comment: HighFaces is not an official wrapper for Highcharts. Perhaps it will be a better idea to contact the author of this wrapper. Check also other wrappers listed here: https://www.highcharts.com/products/wrappers

Comment: Hi, I am the author of HighFaces. HighFaces 1.4 is already on its way and will contain the latest JavaScript base; but you could of course get the source code from SourceForge and do the replacement on your own. However you should be aware, that this way you will not get the improvements that will come together with 1.4.

Comment: Thank you. We will wait for 1.4
Is there any tentative date or could we subscribe to receive notification. I have already sent email to HighFaces support email also.

we are able download 1.3 code